# Does the currying of a closed abelian monoidal category preserves addition?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Let $V$ be a left-closed abelian monoidal category. That is, $V$ is a left-closed monoidal category which is also an abelian category. Let $\Phi:\hom(y\otimes x,z)\to\hom(x,[y,z])$ be the currying of $V$. Then does $\Phi$ preserve addition? That is, for all morphisms $f,g:y\otimes x\to z$, does $\Phi(f+g)=\Phi(f)+\Phi(g)$ hold? This is true for the category of all right $R$-modules, where $R$ is some fixed ring.

Comment: Are you assuming for example that the associativity functors in the monoidal structure are additive functors?  Or are you leaving that as not necessarily assumed as well?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I am not assuming anything other than what I specified in the question. But more assumptions can be added if needed.

Comment: I am not sure but isn't it in general part of the definition? If you have a closed enriched monoidal category, then you have the isomorphism of hom objects in the category of enrichment (in this case **Ab**). Here currying would be a homomorphism of abelian groups.